# Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

Yeah but you can't get reputations in this website at all, so as a result I always have 101 reputations and 101 < 125, so I won't ever be able to downvote, but no way I see that others do this so what's going on?

Comment: You misunderstand how meta.physics works - your reputation here is the same as on the main site, so once you have 125 reptuation on physics.SE, you will also be able to downvote here.

Comment: Erez, you seem to have many brief questions today about how the site works. Would you like to join us in [chat] to hash things out rather than producing many meta questions?

Comment: @rob okay I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation is awarded for participation in [the main site](http://physics.stackexchange.com).  Your reputation will be the same on the main site and on the meta site.